# JQuery keyup events not working in external js file

Tags: jquery

Ok this is just confusing me.
first some background:

I created a html file ( it was actually a php file but the php was just for form validation) I decided to create some javascript to do some validation on the fly like check if the username had already been used. All was working just fine. I then decided I might have a use for this code in other parts of the site so I just started messing around with external js files holding the code.

in the original html code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if($("#userN").val() == ""){
            $("#testUserName").html("");
        }else{
            ajax_search();
        }
        $("#userN").focusout(function(){
            ajax_search();
        });
            $("#userN").keyup(function(){
        ajax_search();
        });
    } );
</script>
```

ajax_search() just sends a request to a php file to test the data with text in the userN input field.

so I copied that and the ajax_search() function to a test.js file I made sure the jquery.js file was called first, then I called the test.js file with that code in it.

The strange thing is the $(document).ready runs

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("test1"); 
    if($("#userN").val() == ""){
        $("#testUserName").html("");
    }else{
        ajax_search();
    }
    $("#userN").focusout(function(){
        ajax_search();
    });
        $("#userN").keyup(function(){
    ajax_search();
    });
    alert("test2");
} );
```

That code will show a popup with test1 then another popup with test2 but the focusout or keyup would not work.

Nothing I did worked until I put all that code back in the html file minus the ajax_search function. Which is what I wanted but I don't understand why the events would not work. Was I doing something wrong? Can it not be done this way?

Comment: Where is the `ajax_search()` function defined? It's possible you're including `test.js` *before* you've included whatever file declares `ajax_search()`

Comment: it was in the test.js file infact if I ran ajax_search() from $(document).ready(); it would run just fine the keyup wasn't working. If I put alert("you pressed a key!") in the .keyup() event it wouldn't fire.

Comment: I forgot to mention there were no errors in the console window of firefox I didn't check the other browsers. No errors what so ever it just didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use

`$("#userN").on('keyup', function(){ ajax_search(); });`

Answer (score 0):

Code seems OK to me, your problem laies somewhere else. Try this code and let us know the result -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("#userN").val() == "") {
        $("#testUserName").html("");
    } else {
        alert("1");
    }
    $("#userN").focusout(function() {
        alert("2");
    });
    $("#userN").keyup(function() {
        alert("3");
    });
}
```

Comment: Adding that code I able to see the alert with the 1, but the focusout and keyup do not do anything? They work once I put them in the <script> tags on the html page, but not in the .js file Maybe I have a bad copy of jquery?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, the problem was that I had document.onkeyup implemented in 2 different files. solution: merge them or delete one of them